# how to pass a data in a django view to other views without globall

Tags: python, django, django-views

so I am using a payment that has a view called verify , and It is going to check if the result was Ok , do something .
But I need to pass order_id in the previous view that is token from the url to this view . some suggestion was using the global . but I am afraid of a error in the real server .

If you need . Its the code :

Previous view that sends a request to the payment center :

```
def send_request(request , order_id):
i = order_id
amount = get_object_or_404(Order , id = i  , user_id = request.user.id)
result = client.service.PaymentRequest(MERCHANT , amount.total , description , email , mobile , CallbackURL)
if result.Status == 100 :
    return redirect('https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/StarPay' + str(result.Authority))
else :
    return HttpResponse('error code : ' , str(result.Status))
```

And I need the order_id in the next view

SO what can i do??Help please!

Comment: can i add the id in the request ? something like the user id that is always in the request . If i can do it , How ?

Comment: you could add it to the url query like ?order_id=x then use that in the next view

Comment: well , I dont think i can do it . there is a setting for the payment center that takes you just an url called  "callback url" . and it will be your verify url . so I cnat change that url in the view ! I mean I think i cant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass data from one view to another can be done in several way in Django.

**You can use url parameter :**

```
def present_view(request):
    if condition:
        return reverse('next_view', args(order_id))
    return render(request, 'present_view.html', locals())

def next_view(request, order_id):
    # Retrieve order_id from url parameter
    id = order_id
    # Do some stuff with id here
```

*urls.py*

```
path('present_view/', views.present_view, name=present_view),
path('next_view/<int:order_id>/', views.next_view, name=next_view)
```

**You can use session :**

```
def present_view(request):
    if condition:
        # Set the id in the session
        request.session['order_id'] = 'some_id_123'
        return reverse('next_view', args(order_id))
    return render(request, 'present_view.html', locals())

def next_view(request, order_id):
    # Retrieve order_id from session, id = 0 if order_id is not found
    id = request.session.get('order_id', 0)
    # Do some stuff with id here
```

*urls.py*

```
path('present_view/', views.present_view, name=present_view),
path('next_view/', views.next_view, name=next_view)
```

Comment: thanks a lot man .

Comment: . just a little question . if we redirect user to a nother website and after that redirect it to our website(whitout closing the browser) , the data in sessions will be in the request agein?

Comment: Yes ! While the browser is open ; the session will be available

Comment: thanks . I try the session part but seems like it does not work for me ! there is the lines but it does not print anything in the terminal

Comment: request.session['order_id'] = i  \ print(request.session.get('order_id'))

Comment: `request.session['order_id'] = 'value'` in the first view and `request.session.get('order_id')` in the second view